# Exe4j Crashes with System Error On Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: exe4j

I am getting a crash immediately at startup with an exe4j executable on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Turned on redirect of stderr and stdout to try to get any message at all, but failed.

Tried 'run as administrator', failed.

Rebuilt the executable, failed.

At this point I cannot think of anything new to try.  Can someone offer a suggestion?

Below are the problem details from the windows dialog.  Any idea what could be causing this?

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX64
  Application Name: DCoreX64.exe
  Application Version:  9.1.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    54d098c4
  Fault Module Name:    DCoreX64.exe
  Fault Module Version: 9.1.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   54d098c4
  Exception Offset: 00000000000049d0
  Exception Code:   c0000409
  Exception Data:   0000000000000000
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 1678
  Additional Information 2: 16789cf0f420663251ee660bfee7765e
  Additional Information 3: 415a
  Additional Information 4: 415aeefa71c8c47ed34c12722ba51457

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Answer (score 0):

My issue turned out to be that the classpath was too long.  Exe4j put out a new release to address it.

Comment: Also confirmed in launch4j, which gave an error about the classpath being too long.  I ended up shortening allot of paths and jar names.  Time to split up this app!